# Creating an api endpoint with Grape that returns a nested hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-grape

I'm having trouble trying to set up my first API.  I have the API endpoint working with Grape, but I'm not sure how to get the correct data hash that I want.

Right now the API is very simple and looks like this:

```
    module CategoryTopic
      class API < Grape::API
        prefix "api/v1"
        format :json

        resource "categories" do
          get do
            Category.all
          end
        end

      end
    end
```

And that returns this

```
[{"id":1,"category_name":"General Questions"}]
```

But inside of my app, a category has_many topics, and I want to return a hash that looks like this:

```
{categories: 
  {"Numbers": "1", "2"},
  {"Colors": "Red", "Blue"}
}
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. I'm assuming that you want to return that JSON from the **/api/v1/categories** URL.

First off, I don't agree with your proposed JSON because it doesn't seem right. If a Category has a has_many association with Topics, the result JSON should return the Category attributes and all relevant associations inside it. In my opinion, it should be something like this:

```
[
    { "id":"1", "category_name": "General Questions", 
          topics: [ { "numbers":["1", "2"], "colors": ["Red", "Blue"] } ] }
]
```

In this case, you have to install the Grape Entity gem (https://github.com/intridea/grape-entity) and create two entities like these:

```
class CategoryEntity < Grape::Entity
    expose :id
    expose :category_name
    expose :topics, :using => TopicEntity
end

class TopicEntity < Grape::Entity
    expose :numbers
    expose :colors
end
```

It's always a good practice to not directly return your models from your API. You should use an Entity to shield your model representation from your API clients. Next, **require** this gem and use your brand new entities in your API class like this:

```
require 'grape-entity'

module CategoryTopic
  class API < Grape::API
    prefix "api/v1"
    format :json

    resource "categories" do
      get do
        present Category.all, :with => CategoryEntity
      end
    end

  end
end
```